# Implementing RevealLayout in between actvities

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

What would be the best way to implement [`RevealLayout`](https://github.com/kyze8439690/RevealLayout) in between activities? The answer the developer gave in the open bug is incredibly vague and I would like a bit more guidance. Also, if there's a better way of approaching it than with `RevealLayout`, I would appreciate any other ideas.

Looking to implement it on the `ImageButton` below when pressed.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am finding the same answer but to no avail. As per my understanding we can't add a RevealLayout between activities we can add transition animation between them. If you have some answers plz post it below.